# HTML: how to use colspan and rowspan?

Tags: html

I am trying to build a very simple array, but somehow It is not working How I think it should. Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table width=100%>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="8">sigle row of 8 cols</th>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td colspan="2">2 cols </td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="6" > 6 cols</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">2 cols</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">2 cols</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to debug.
I want the months to occupy only 2 column and the saving to occupy 6 columns (the rest), but, this is not working as expected. I know the answer is trivial, but I cannot find it. Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table will have 8 columns, but you have effectively reduced it to 2. The table rendering algorithm will make things as efficient as it can.

By adding an additional row you can see what is happening

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table width=100%>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="8">Monthly Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td colspan="2">January</td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="6" >$30000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">February</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">March</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

What you are better off doing is assigning width to the columns

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table width=100%>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Monthly Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td style="width:33%">January</td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="width:66%" >$30000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>March</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes this is how I want it, but, the width of  the first cell should be 2/8 and the second cell 6/8

Comment: If you want teh first cell to be 2/8 (=1/4) and the second one to be 6/8 (=3/4), then just set the width to 25% and 75% and don't use colspans to achieve this (apart from the header that is).

Answer (score 1):

because the you add `heading in single <th>` so make id different

```
<th colspan="2">Monthly</th>
<th colspan="6">Savings</th>
```

so it will display `2 for month` and `6 for saving`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table width=100%>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Monthly</th>
      <th colspan="6">Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">January</td>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="6">$30000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">February</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">March</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank, but I want a single row on the header. This data is just for the demo.